# MYSQL join tables multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys, referential-integrity

I have a table, with rows of events, and each one has (amongst lots of other fields) `addedbyuser`, `editedbyuser`, `deletedbyuser`
There are `INT`, and refer back to the `users` table to a particular user.
I am able to join one of the fields (say `addedbyuser`) without any problems, how do i join the rest and reference them in php?

events table:

```
eventid addedbyuser editedbyuser deletedbyuser
1       1           2            3
```

users table:

```
id username
1  name1
2  name2
3  name3
```

So basically, I want to display the names of who added, edited and deleted the article, can I do this in one SQL query?

Answer (score 16):

Something like this:

```
select 
    evn.eventid, 
    us1.username as addedbyuser, 
    us2.username as editedbyuser, 
    us3.username as deletedbyuser, 
from events evn
    join users as us1 on
        evn.addedbyuser = us1.id
    join users as us2 on
        evn.editedbyuser = us2.id
    join users as us3 on
        evn.deletedbyuser = us3.id
```